# Kitchen range hood install electrical outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle, range-hood

I would like to replace my under cabinet kitchen range hood.

The old range hood was direct wire, but the new one is plug in.

I have a a hot, neutral, and ground wire under the cabinet (to the right of the vent in the wall in the picture). The hot and neutral wires is sufficient length to reach into the cabinet above, but the romex sheath isn't long enough.

Is it allowed by code to have the hot and neutral wires run without romex sheath into a new electrical outlet box that I install inside the cabinet above the current location of the wires? I would also extend the ground wire (via a wirenut and another length of ground wire) into the electrical box inside the cabinet as well?

If it's not allowed, what can I do?

[image]

Comment: Does the romex come from below or above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sheath must enter the box. You also can not have wire nuts outside a box, so you would not be able to extend the ground as you describe.

I suggest two boxes: one right there where the cable is right now, and a second one in the cabinet above. Then run a new "Romex" from one box to the other. Put a blank cover on the box behind the hood, and a receptacle in the cabinet. (I strongly recommend a metal box for this installation.)

Alternatively, where does the cable exit the hood? The hood may have a hard-wired option that lines up with your existing cable in the wall and you remove the cord altogether. If so, the hood becomes the "box". BUT don't invent a solution here; you must follow the manufacturers instructions to meet code.

Answer (score 3):

Boxes are not allowed to be "buried" where they are inaccessible. I am not sure whether putting a box behind the hood (as suggested by longneck) would violate that or not. Would require a careful reading of some definitions in the code, and even then local inspector might not agree.

However, a box inside a cabinet, accessible by opening the door, is definitely allowed. Depending on where the wire comes from, you might be able to put a box in a cabinet to the side--same height or below--then run new wire from there as suggested by longneck. (Or just put your outlet there.)

Comment: I've seen exactly that setup for combination microwave oven/hood - receptacle in the cabinet above with cord run through a hole in the cabinet.

Comment: If the wire comes from above, the is 100% the right option. Cut the hole in the cabinet & wall, pull the wire up out of the old box, install a new box in the wall, wire it to a receptacle, plug the hood into the new outlet. No hidden outlets, no buried wire junctions, no worries at all. Of course, if the wire comes up from below... :(